# Using UNIQUE not in a certain order and keeping data organized

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

First, here is an example based on the original sheet for better understanding and help, I will refer to it in my explanation:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MDqyY2EnSCFuzbZ1gyaeUygKa5hv-2nGnnhwrrtHgRk/edit?usp=sharing

Columns A:C are basically a database, where the order number and products(columns A&B) are known and filled immediately, but column C is filled only somewhat later. sometimes days, or even weeks.
In the meantime, it is possible that new rows with order # and products were added, like row 6(Order #5).

In a different tab, I have a formula for unique invoice #(column F), and to the right of this column I have manually filled data, like invoice subtotal and if it was paid or not.

The problem is when I add a new invoice # to row 6 for example (Let's say C6 value is 28), then the invoice number appears in the middle of column F and pushes down 'previous' invoice numbers, which causes the data that is in columns G and H not to correlate with column F as it was originally put.

Is there a way to fill column F based on the time column C cells were filled and not their actual sheet order?
Or, alternatively, link the values written in G and H to a certain value in F so they will move along with it when it is pushed down?

Comment: possible but you will need timestamp script - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=timestamp+%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to understand what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Do you just want to have a total per invoice number? That could probably be easily achieved with SUMIF formulas